# Format all the numbers on an app [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to format **all** the numbers on a flutter app?
By formatting I mean, for example, given a number (eg 4000) it’s shown on the UI as 4,000.
I know that there’s a way to do so using the intl package, but in that case, from what I know, I have to format each number individually and it’s not the most optimal thing to do in my case.

Comment: There's no real way to go through all your actual numbers and convert them automatically, you will have to do that part

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumberFormat passing a custom format in ICU formatting pattern, take a look in [NumberFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html).

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var formatter = NumberFormat('#,##,000');
  print(formatter.format(16987));
  print(formatter.format(13876));
  print(formatter.format(456786));
}
```

Output

```
 16,987
 13,876
 4,56,786
```